# Replacement for PreAuthenticate in portable class libraries

Tags: httpwebrequest, credentials, portable-class-library

I am porting a library to a PCL and have to find a solution for managing HTTP request credentials. I took away concrete credentials classes like CredentialCache (that is not portable) and is now only using ICredentials, so client applications may create proper credentials and just send an interface reference.

However one thing still needs to be resolved. On some platforms HttpWebRequest has a neat PreAuthenticate property that takes care of initial handshaking. Without it the client needs to catch and repsponds to 401 responses. But PreAuthenticate is not a part of most of PCL profiles, and I wonder if there is any resolution to that or the client will need to implement replacement logic itself (which is silly since this is a standard piece of code).

Thanks in advance

Comment: What platforms are you targeting in your PCL?

Comment: I am targeting NET403+NET45+WinRT+SL5+WP8 but Silvelight is not a demand. I checked that PreAuthenticate is only available in HttpClientHandler and only in .NET45. HttpWebRequest does not have it in any PCL version. Without it setting credentials can require some extra coding. Since this is a standard routine, I wonder why isn't it available and what is the workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PreAuthenticate can be set using HttpClienHandler that HttpClient accepts as a parameter constructor, e.g.:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    PreAuthenticate = true
};
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write the code to handle this yourself.  An API will only be portable if it is available on all of the platforms you target.  In this case PreAuthenticate was a new API in .NET 4.5 and Windows Store apps, so it won't be available in a Portable Class Library if you are targeting any other platforms (ie .NET 4, Silverlight, or Windows Phone).

Comment: Daniel, but PreAuthenticate has been available since .NET 2.0, not just .NET 4.5! It's a very old WebRequest property and quite useful since it hides quite a lot of complexity when establishing an HTTP communication with authentication. This is why I don't understand why it was left out in portable library world.

Comment: @VagifAbilov OK, I was looking in the wrong place.  However, it looks like this API was never supported in Silverlight or on Windows Phone (unless of course I'm mistaken again :)).  That would be why it isn't available in portable libraries targeting those platforms.

Comment: Daniel, it's correct that it's never been supported on SL and WP8. But what about desktop platforms? This API is not present for either WebRequest or HttpWebRequest for _any_ platform (I am looking at your Excel spreadsheet). It would save lots of efforts on WSA/NET4x platforms if it was available there for PCL.

Comment: @VagifAbilov It is supported on portable libraries targeting .NET 4.5 and Windows Store apps.  I'm not exactly sure why it's not supported when you target .NET 4 with PCLs, it may be because at the time there were no other platforms it was supported on so it wasn't included.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure, Daniel? I just created a PCL with support for .NET 4.5 and WSA. Declared HttpWebRequest variable. It does not have PreAuthenticate property. And this is in accordance to the PCL API Excel doc that does not list PreAuthenticate as supported property for HttpWebRequest or WebRequest in PCL, in fact for any platform.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. I tried to set Credentials to a single NetworkCredental(user, pass), but it doesn't work in WinRT, although it works in Windoes Phone. So far the only way to make it work in WinRT is to create the CredentialCache by reflection.

```
var credCacheType = Type.GetType("System.Net.CredentialCache, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
var credCache = credCacheType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]).Invoke(new object[0]);
var addMethod = credCacheType.GetMethod("Add", new Type[] { typeof(Uri), typeof(string), typeof(NetworkCredential) });
addMethod.Invoke(credCache, new object[] { new Uri(_server), "Digest", Credential });
request.Credentials = (ICredentials)credCache;
```